# Форматирование тескта

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Есть большой скрипт вот ссылка на него https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/42315/
я хочу вставить в `USERNAME = 'тут логин'`, я пробовал через `{0}`,`%s`, но это все выдавало ошибку. Как я могу вставить туда свой текст?

Пример(Специально обрезал кое-где, но когда я тестирую там полноценный скрипт):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
gen = r"""#!/usr/bin/python
from impacket import smb, smbconnection
from mysmb import MYSMB
from struct import pack, unpack, unpack_from
import sys
import socket
import time

'''
MS17-010 exploit for Windows 2000 and later by sleepya

Note:
- The exploit should never crash a target (chance should be nearly 0%)
- The exploit use the bug same as eternalromance and eternalsynergy, so named pipe is needed

Tested on:
- Windows 2016 x64
- Windows 10 Pro Build 10240 x64
- Windows 2012 R2 x64
- Windows 8.1 x64
- Windows 2008 R2 SP1 x64
- Windows 7 SP1 x64
- Windows 2008 SP1 x64
- Windows 2003 R2 SP2 x64
- Windows XP SP2 x64
- Windows 8.1 x86
- Windows 7 SP1 x86
- Windows 2008 SP1 x86
- Windows 2003 SP2 x86
- Windows XP SP3 x86
- Windows 2000 SP4 x86
'''

USERNAME = '{0}'
PASSWORD = ''

'''
A transaction with empty setup:
- it is allocated from paged pool (same as other transaction types) on Windows 7 and later
- it is allocated from private heap (RtlAllocateHeap()) with no on use it on Windows Vista and earlier
- no lookaside or caching method for allocating it

Note: method name is from NSA eternalromance

For Windows 7 and later, it is good to use matched pair method (one is large pool and another one is fit
for freed pool from large pool). Additionally, the exploit does the information leak to check transactions
alignment before doing OOB write. So this exploit should never crash a target against Windows 7 and later.

For Windows Vista and earlier, matched pair method is impossible because we cannot allocate transaction size
smaller than PAGE_SIZE (Windows XP can but large page pool does not split the last page of allocation). But
a transaction with empty setup is allocated on private heap (it is created by RtlCreateHeap() on initialing server).
Only this transaction type uses this heap. Normally, no one uses this transaction type. So transactions alignment
in this private heap should be very easy and very reliable (fish in a barrel in NSA eternalromance). The drawback
of this method is we cannot do information leak to verify transactions alignment before OOB write.
So this exploit has a chance to crash target same as NSA eternalromance against Windows Vista and earlier.
'''

'''
Reversed from: SrvAllocateSecurityContext() and SrvImpersonateSecurityContext()
win7 x64
struct SrvSecContext {
    DWORD xx1; // second WORD is size
    DWORD refCnt;
    PACCESS_TOKEN Token;  // 0x08
    DWORD xx2;
   40,
    'TRANS_OUTPARAM_OFFSET' : 0x44,
    'TRANS_INDATA_OFFSET' : 0x48,
    'TRANS_OUTDATA_OFFSET' : 0x4c,
    'TRANS_PARAMCNT_OFFSET' : 0x58,
    'TRANS_TOTALPARAMCNT_OFFSET' : 0x5c,
    'TRANS_FUNCTION_OFFSET' : 0x72,
    'TRANS_MID_OFFSET' : 0x80,
}

WIN7_64_TRANS_INFO = {
    'TRANS_SIZE' : 0xf8,  # struct size
    'TRANS_FLINK_OFFSET' : 0x28,
    'TRANS_INPARAM_OFFSET' : 0x70,
    'TRANS_OUTPARAM_OFFSET' : 0x78,

pipe_name = None if len(sys.argv) < 3 else sys.argv[2]

exploit(target, pipe_name)
print('Done')""".format('text')
```

Получаю:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testt.py", line 1000, in <module>
    print('Done')""".format('text')
KeyError: '\n    DWORD xx1; // second WORD is size\n    DWORD refCnt;\n    PACCE
SS_TOKEN Token;  // 0x08\n    DWORD xx2;\n    BOOLEAN CopyOnOpen; // 0x14\n    B
OOLEAN EffectiveOnly;\n    WORD xx3;\n    DWORD ImpersonationLevel; // 0x18\n
 DWORD xx4;\n    BOOLEAN UsePsImpersonateClient; // 0x20\n'
```

Comment: Как именно пробовали, какую ошибку выдавало?

Comment: Добавил пример.

Comment: скорее всего вам надо экранировать все фигурные скобки кроме скобок в строке `USERNAME = '{0}'`, структуры же тоже обозначаются фигурными скобками.

Comment: Я вас не понял.

Comment: Вообщем я не нашел решения для моего вопроса, но я сделал по другому.  Я скачиваю через wget этот файл считываю его, через .replace() заменяю что мне надо, все работает.

Comment: `struct SrvSecContext {...}` это тоже обрабатывается методом `format`. Но можно экранировать скобки вот так `struct SrvSecContext {{...}}` , тогда метод будет игнорировать их. Это надо сделать со всеми фигурными скобками. А какое исключение появлялось при использовании `"%" %`?

Comment: Вообще такие задачи обычно решаются передаче параметров в скрипт через командную строку.